# How to set bin size in Bar Plot, Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I try to define bin size for a bar blot to change the width of each bar in ploty. I can do it using border width of `Marker` in plotly. But when the size of the border is increased, its height will be changed too. Hence, the question is how can I set the width of each bar in a bar plot in plotly?

The code of the first trick is coming in the following (each object for each bar):

```
data = [go.Bar(
x = [1],
y = [100], 
marker=go.Marker(
        color = 'blue',
        line=go.Line(
            color='blue',  # set bar border color
            width= 2     # set bar border width
        )
    )
),
go.Bar(
x = [2],
y = [200], 
marker=go.Marker(
        color = 'red',
        line=go.Line(
            color='red',  # set bar border color
            width= 440,      # set bar border width
        )
    )
)]
```

Comment: The problem was in version of plotly which does not work on zeppelin and also on local apps. Upgrade to version 3.9 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The width property of each bar graph will help you set the individual widths. Just keep in mind that if the width is `greater than 1` then there is overlap between the adjacent bar graph, so try contraining the value between `1 and 0`. Please tryout the below example.

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from pandas_datareader import data as web
from datetime import datetime as dt
import plotly.graph_objs as go

app = dash.Dash()
data = [go.Bar(
x = [1],
y = [100],
width=1,
marker=go.Marker(
        color = 'blue'
    )
)
,
go.Bar(
x = [2],
y = [200], 
width=0.6,
marker=go.Marker(
        color = 'red'
    )
)
]
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for Python.
    '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': data,
            'layout': {
                'title': 'Dash Data Visualization',
            'xaxis': { 'range': [0,4], 'nticks':20, 'dticks': 0.5}
            }
        }
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: It doesnot work in python. I mean there is no error about this method, but it's not applied in python.

Comment: @OmG Sorry I don't get you, I tested the code in my local system, what is the issue?